# converting from system::String to std::string

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli

To convert from a system::String to an std::string, I use the following code:

```
IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(PORT);
string newString = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
```

However, the place where I got the code uses

```
IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(PORT);
char* newString = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
```

For some reason though, I get garbage in newString if I do the char* version.  Anyone know why this would happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `std::string` version works is because it immediately creates a privatecopy of the `char*` value.  This private copy is not affected by the later `FreeHGlobal`.

The `char*` version is assigned a pointer to memory which you then free on the very next line.  It's invalid the moment the `FreeHGlobal` command executes.

Answer (score 0):

you can   Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters with **std::string::c_str**
then initialize the String^  with the char array

```
std::string bla = "ConvertMe";
String^ ResultString= gcnew String(bla.c_str());
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.